# Did Rama have multiple wives?

Tags: ramayana, krishna, rama

I strongly believed that Rama has a single wife, Sita. But I know that Krishna has multiple wives.

But [this blog](http://daily.bhaskar.com/news/JM-shocking-ramayan-fact-lord-rama-had-many-wives-apart-from-sita-4372857-PHO.html) says that Rama has multiple wives and it's told in Valmiki Ramayana. Is it true? Did Rama really have multiple wives like Krishna?

Which one is more credible? Ramayana by Valmiki or Tulasidas?

**EDIT**:

[Here's the verse](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga8/ayodhyaroman8.htm#Verse12) from Valmiki Ramayana (Manthara speaking to Kaikeyi):

> hṛṣṭāḥ khalu bhaviṣyanti **rāmasya paramāḥ striyaḥ** | 
> aprahṛṣṭā bhaviṣyanti snuṣāste bharatakṣaye || 2-8-12
>
> **Rama's great wives** will get delighted. Your daughters-in-law will be unhappy because of Bharata's waning position.

Comment: Link you gave has no reference like kaand, chapter and verse so it is not rrliable source.

Comment: @VipulHadiya The link does a specific chapter and Khanda, namely Ayodhya Kanda chapter 8.  Here is the verse being discussed: "Rama's wives will get delighted. Your daughters-in-law will be unhappy because of Bharata's waning position." http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga8/ayodhya_8_frame.htm

Comment: Valmiki's version is the much much older version, his was the original. I did a study almost 20 years ago on the differences between Tulasidas's version and Valmiki's version. There are subtle differences. I don't remember a reference to multiple wives. One of the biggest differences is that Tulasidas makes Lord Rama into a brahmin instead of a kayastya. I no longer have a copy of Tulasidas's Ramayana. It is better to refer to a hardcopy book than an internet version.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Where does Tulasidasa make Rama into a **Brahmin**? Wasn't he a Kshatriya of Raghukula? And what is Kayastya?

Comment: You should know that Rama had only one wife.

Comment: Rama has only one wife.

Comment: @moonstar2001 yes, you are right. misspelling on my part.

Comment: @Surya No longer have my notes and it was some 20 years ago as I said. I have a vague remembrance that it might have been somewhere shortly before, during, or shortly after the marriage ceremony.

Comment: Rama okka-sol, okka-banam, okka-taram (one-word, one-arrow and one-wife), sings Thyagaraja.

Comment: @ram Tyagaraja did not sing in Tamil. The exact words must be used when quoting.

Comment: @moonstar2001, i mixed words from both telugu and tamil ('okka') is telugu.. from internet it looks like exact words were - 'okka mata okka banam okka patni'

Comment: @PrakashRP There are no berses from Valmiki Ramayana supporting it.

Comment: Would you have a look at the following excerpt?                                                              ' Taking Sita by the hand, Kakutstha gave her delicious wine made of distilled honey ... whilst lovely Apsaras ... began to perform... and troops of Nymphs ... surrounded by the Kinneris intoxicated with wine, danced before Kakutstha, and the virtuous Rama,... '                                                                                                         (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424813.html)

Comment: @PrakashRP The paragraph is saying nothing about partners (wives) other than Sita.

Comment: @PrakashRP Kings use to enjoy singing and dancing of women, doesn't mean they are engaged with women.

Comment: hanugm, 'partners' do Not mean 'wives' Really. By 'wives', the married partners are meant.

Comment: hanugm, you've invented another novel sophistry, but it's Sillier than the former one. No sensible guys believe that kings that ' enjoy singing and dancing of women ' do Not enjoy touching & sleeping with seductive women. There's No grounds for believing that Rama, if he were a virile man, did Not relish the gratification of his carnal desire with those women. It was Not immoral, and gods are used to relishing free love in heaven. Rama knew of it, didN't he ?

Comment: @PrakashRP It is necessary to understand the qualities of Rama before concluding. If we read [Bala-kanda](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=1&language=dv&field_sarga_value=1), it will be clearer. Rama is *जितेन्द्रिय: conquered the senses* and *धृतिमान् selfcommanding, वशी subjecting the senses (subjecting the entire world under his control)*. So, we cannot compare Rama with other Virile man, who cannot control their senses.

Comment: @PrakashRP And the dharmas in heaven are different from human dharmas on earth. You can read [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03046.htm) regarding Arjuna, who rejected Urvasi's offer.

Comment: Are you ware that you're suggesting that Rama did Not father Lava & Kusha, Sita's sons?      If Rama were so ' जितेन्द्रिय ' Really, he would Not relish his addiction to wine & Apsaras.

Comment: @PrakashRP He married and beget children inorder to [clear his debt](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14831/661). As I already mentioned, you can share corresponding Sanskrit slokhas. Then, the ambiguity can be cleared.

Comment: Well, anyone can justify his addiction to drugs, alcohol & sexy dames on similar grounds.

Comment: What about the story of Manu and Shatarupa : ' He, the Viraj called Manu, was united with her, his daughter called Satarupa, whom he conceived of as his wife. From that union men were born. ' (  Brihadaranyaka Upanishad (1.4.3) with Shankara Bhashya translated by Swami Madhavananda )
The next verse ( Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.4 ) says : In order to prevent her genitor from raping her, Shatarupa tried to hide herself by assuming the form of a ' cow ' ; but then Manu turned himself into a ' bull ' and raped her, and thus cows were created.  This is how all animals evolved on the earth.

Comment: @PrakashRP Please share me the translation link for the same.

Comment: Here it is : https://archive.org/details/Brihadaranyaka.Upanishad.Shankara.Bhashya.by.Swami.Madhavananda/page/n129/mode/2up

Comment: hanugm, there's Really No good Reason for you, if you're a True ' जितेन्द्रिय ', Not a Fake, to spend nights in 5-Star hotels and relish Sumptuous dishes, Foreign liquor, and sexy girls, is there ?

Comment: @PrakashRP I didn't read the translation yet. But, I am guessing that Satarupa is not a daughter to Manu since she is the first women.

Comment: @PrakashRP The same Rama spent with out any boghas during both vanavasa and after sending Sita to Valmiki ashram. If having dishes and juices, watching dance, listening songs are allowed according to dharma, then Rama can perform them as a king but not as a servant of senses.

Comment: @PrakashRP There is no need to leave all dharmic bhogas to prove as a ' जितेन्द्रिय '. But, please provide me corresponding Sanskrit slokhas so that I can ask for actual translation on out site.

Comment: You should read it carefully. If you can prove your thesis, you'll certainly deserve to be credited with a new Discovery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127467/discussion-between-prakash-rp-and-hanugm).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rama's father Maharaja Dasaratha had 3 Queens and 350 other wives. On the other hand, Rama is **Ekapatni Vrata**, the man who wedded only once. Sitadevi is his only wife.

This is illustrated many times in the Ramayana, prominently in the episode of Surpanakha, where he denies her proposal saying he is **Krta Darah**, meaning one who has already married - this implies his Ekapatni Vrata.

Moreover, the chapter linked in the question contains a monologue by Manthara, who was at that time in the process of poisoning Kaikeyi's mind. So her opinion of Rama is *not really reliable.* Even so, the words she speaks are to be noted:

She says:

> Hrshtah Khalu **Bhavishyanti** Ramasya **Paramah Striyah**|
>   Aprahishtah Bhavishyanti Snushaas Te Bharata-kshaye||

Here, she says, Bhavishyanti, which means, "Will become". So the verse, if put into the following anvaya:

> Hrshtah, Paramah Striyah Ramasya Khalu Bhavishyanti,

it means, being delighted (Hrshtah), the princesses (Paramah Striyah - literally great women) will become Rama's (wives).

So it does refer to marriages of Rama **after** he becomes the King.

Furthermore, in the Uttara Kanda, the priests of Rama advise him to marry someone else, so that he would be able to perform the Ashvamedha Yajna, which would not have been said if Rama had multiple wives. Even at this point, Rama refuses to marry and instead seats beside him a golden image of Sita.

Also, the idea that what we follow today is Tulasidasa's Ramayana, and not Valmiki's, is another fragment of Mr CR Sreenivasa Iyengar's wild imagination.

The Ramayana as we know it is definitely **influenced** by Tulasidasa, in places like the meeting of Rama and Sita in Mithila Gardens and Lakshmana's Rekha, but on the whole, most versions remain faithful to Valmiki.

(And by most versions, I include only versions entitled 'Ramayana', not 'Ramacharitamanas' or 'Kamba Ramayana' or any others.)

Comment: @sv. Means I will cite suitable sources and complet the answer. The link is which hanugm referred to. It's in the question.

Comment: @sv. Well I wasn't going to leave my answer just like that. Your research into the legal aspects is amusing. I never delved into that area.

Comment: @Surya nice explanation. All these kind of  misapprehensions in Sanatana Dharma will vanish if everyone learn our scriptures in Sanskrit.

Comment: @AnilKumar I know. It is my luck that I picked it up as a 2nd language.

Comment: I agree with @sv. - you shouldn't just post an incomplete answer and then fill it in later.  You should wait until you've finished writing the answer and then post something.  In the mean time copy what you've written to Notepad or something if you're worried it will be lost from a browser crash.

Comment: @Keshav But I have completed my answer! And if you remember I did the same thing with the Nappinai question.

Comment: Yeah, I know you complete the answers later on, but in future why don't you just hold off on posting the answer until it's done?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Okie Dokie. :)

Answer (score 13):

Rama is a Ekaptni Vrata. I have quoted what was mentioned in valmiki ramayan, 
**In valmiki ramayan, manathara tells the below words to Kaikeyi, Thus, if you become Kausalya's servant-maid along with us, your son Bharata will be Rama's attendant. Rama's wives will get delighted. Your daughters-in-law will be unhappy because of Bharata's waning position."**

***Comment: The words 'Rama's wives' here do not indicate that Rama had multiple wives. Manathara refers to a possible future where Rama being a King would marry other women. It was a norm then for a king to have more than one wife.***

Pl. refer to the below link, http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ayodhya/sarga8/ayodhya_8_prose.htm .

Comment: The commentary is by the translator (Sri K. M. K. Murthy), it's not part of actual Valmiki Ramayana. So, IMO, it cannot be a conclusive answer to OP's question.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Logically make sense for me

Answer (score 3):

Let me again post conclusive evidence of Rama’s Ek Patni Vrata. (All the reference are from the critical edition Valmiki Ramayana, Princeton university press by Pollock)

Dasrath ( to Rama) in Ayodhya Kanda

Therefore today **you and your wife** must take a vow to remain chaste this night, too fast and sleep upon a bed of darbha grass. Have your friends guard you warily today at every turn (4-20- 25, Ayodhya Kanda)

Dashrath to Vashistha

When he had given Rama his instructions regarding the 5.1consecration on the coming day, the lord of men summoned his family priest Vashistha and said: “Go, ascetic, and assist **Kakutstha and his wife** in undertaking a fast today, so that ´my son, a man strict in his vows, may gain majesty, glory and kingship.” “So be it,” said the holy Vas´ıshtha, greatest of Vedic scholars, in reply to the king, and he went himself to Rama’s residence. (5-1, Ayodhya Kanda)

Valmiki reporting

When the family priest had gone Rama bathed and then, restraining his desire, he worshipped Narayana in the ´company of his **large-eyed wife**. (6-1, Pollock)

At the sight of him approaching they at once informed Rama and his wife, eager to announce the news. Pollock (14-5)

Ayodhya Kanda is repeatedly implying ONLY one wife

Other members of this site have given a very convincing answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Commenting on [the verse](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga8/ayodhyaroman8.htm#Verse12), C. V. Vaidya, in [*The Riddle of the Rāmāyaṇa*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.495179/page/n23/mode/2up), says that the current Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa suggests Rāma had more than one wife, Sītā being the *mahiṣī*, the consecrated queen.

> According to the present Rāmāyaṇa, Rāma appears to have had many wives. Kālidāsa and later poets mention that he had one wife only (ananyajāneḥ saivāsīdyasmājjāyā hiraṇmayī). **The present Rāmāyaṇa seems to represent that Rāma had one mahiṣī or crowned queen but had many other wives** (not concubines) as was usual with Kṣatriya princes in his days. Says Mantharā to Kaikeyī in the Rāmāyaṇa:
>
> > hṛṣṭāḥ khalu bhaviṣyanti rāmasya paramāḥ striyaḥ | 
> > aprahṛṣṭā bhaviṣyanti snuṣāste bharatakṣaye ||
>
> The commentator says nothing on this śloka; in fact it is impossible to suggest that striyaḥ simply means the handmaids and attendants of Sītā for that word is evidently in contrast with snuṣāḥ or daughters-in-law. And this śloka also goes to show that Bharata too had many wives. Daśaratha also is said in the present Rāmāyaṇa to have had 350 wives besides his three queens. When he called his wives together as Rāma was about to depart for Daṇḍakāraṇya, "Three hundred fifty young women with red eyes surrounding Kauśalyā slowly moved in the observance of a vow."
>
> > ardha sapta śatāḥ tāḥ tu pramadāḥ tāmra locanāḥ | 
> > kausalyām parivārya atha śanaiḥ jagmur dhṛta vratāḥ ||
>
> No doubt is left about their status as further on they are styled as the mothers of Rāma. Thus it appears that Daśaratha and Bharata and Rāma all had many wives besides their consecrated queens. And in this way only can we explain so far as the present Rāmāyaṇa is concerned, the fact that when Sītā was banished by Rāma, **he had her golden image for his wife at the time of the performance of a sacrifice. For, a consecrated queen alone can participate in the performance of a religious ceremony.** In the sacrifice of Daśaratha, only his three queens and notably Kauśalyā took part in the actual performance of the ceremony. However, we may interpret this fact of the golden image of Sītā we cannot get over the śloka quoted in the beginning of this paragraph; **the import of which is plain and unquestionable and we have the strange fact before us viz., that Rāma is represented in the present Rāmāyaṇa to have had more wives than one.**

He however adds this note:

> Probably, this śloka has been put in by the last compiler under influence of the manners of his days. The original Rāmāyaṇa of Vālmīki probably showed Rāma to have had one wife only.

In Sheldon Pollock's [translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=reuTjwEACAAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA97#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [notes](http://www.claysanskritlibrary.org/excerpts/ayodhya/ayodhya-notes.php#d1e10921), we can see how various traditional Rāmāyaṇa commentators explain the phrase, *rāmasya paramāḥ striyaḥ*:

> Sarga 8
>
> 5. "Delight is truly in store for Rama's exalted women, and all that is in store for your daughters-in-law is misery, at Bharata's downfall."
>
> NOTES
>
> 5. "Rāma's exalted women" (rāmasya paramāḥ striyaḥ): The plural has exercised some commentators, since Rāma's monogamy is repeatedly stressed in the text. The simple explanation, given and defended at length by Cg [Bhūṣaṇa], is that **all the women who attend Rāma are meant to be included** (Ck [Amṛtakataka], "'Rāma's women,' namely, **those who are on his side**"; Cm [Tattvadīpikā], Ct [Tilaka] "the plurals [here and in the next clause] denote the **friends of Sītā** and those of Bharata's wife, respectively"). But in 5.16.15 (see 18.16), as in MBh 15.41.18, the locution seems to mean "wives," and to have almost a technical sense. Moreover, the plural "daughters-in-law" in the very next line would seem to suggest (despite Cg) that the princes, like their father, all had more than one wife (5.26.14, cited by Cg, supports this notion, to some extent, and see also Book Six, App. I, No. 10, line 91; for Bharata, see also 75.7 and 94.42). The NR [Northern Recension] reads the singular in both places (139*; we see no reason to believe that the NR has retained "a genuine older tradition," with Shah 1980, p. 98; M4 is a contaminated and virtually worthless manuscript).