# Can I please have a scriptural reference for Pitru Runa?

Tags: scripture, belief, pitru

I heard that in Hinduism, we must beget offspring after marriage as part of Hindu belief (Pitru Runa).  In other words is there scripture about the importance of carrying on a blood line? Is it mandatory to follow it? If so, what scriptures describe this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if you marry you need to grow your lineage. According to [Shatapath Brahmana](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1231.htm), there are four types of debt to everyone as: debt to Gods (Deva Rina), debt to Rishis (Rishi Rina), debt to Fathers (Pitri/Pitru Rina) and debt to Men (Manava/Manushya Rina).

To get free from Pitri Rina you should grow your lineage.

> And further, inasmuch as he is bound to wish for offspring, for that reason he is born as (owing) a debt to the fathers: hence when there is (provided by him) a continued, uninterrupted lineage, it is for them that he does this.

Similar thing has been said in [Yajurveda, Taittiriya sanhita](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv06.htm).

> A Brahman on birth is born with a threefold debt, of pupilship to the Rsis, of sacrifice to the gods, of offspring to the Pitrs. He is freed from his debt who has a son, is a sacrificer, and who has lived as a pupil