# Were Śrī Rāma's brothers - Bharata, Lakṣmaṇa & Śatrughna also 'Eka-patnī-vrata'?

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita, lakshmana, ramcharitmanas

As discussed in this [accepted QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9772/did-rama-have-multiple-wives/26789#26789), that Śrī Rāma maintained 'Eka-patnī-vrata'.

My question is:

- Did Śrī Rāma's three brothers viz. Bharata, Lakṣmaṇa & Śatrughna too, pledged with the 'Eka-patnī-vrata'?
- If not, what's the story/information on the 'other-spouses' of the other three brothers?

Comment: I think people generally did second marriage due to diplomatic reasons or in case the first queen was unable to bear a child. So, it was a king only thing.  Marrying second wives for lust is obviously not dharmic.  Good men like them will not indulge in it obviously. Also no rich father would give his daughter to an already married man.